# Facebook Connect Graph API get notification when successfully sharing to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook, notifications

I use this code to share to facebook:

```
[appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:appDelegate];
```

How can i get the notification (like sharekit) when sharing is successful?

I want to show UIAlertView but i do not know which facebook method that i need to put the UIAlertView.

I try in this method:

```
- (void)dialogDidSucceed:(NSURL *)url {

if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dialogCompleteWithUrl:)]) {
    [_delegate dialogCompleteWithUrl:url];
}


UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle: @"Sharing to Facebook"
                     message: @"Success" 
                     delegate:self
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


[self setAlertSuccess:alert];
[alertSuccess show];
[alert release];

NSLog(@"SUCCESS 2");
[self dismissWithSuccess:YES animated:YES];
}
```

It is working however, when i click cancel button, this method is also called. So where is the right one to put the success alert view?

Answer (score 2):

I am new in IOS.
    These are changes i made in FBDialog.m

```
- (void)dismissWithSuccess:(BOOL)success animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (success) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook Login Sucessful!" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dialogDidComplete:)]) {
            [_delegate dialogDidComplete:self];



        }
    } else {
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dialogDidNotComplete:)]) {
            [_delegate dialogDidNotComplete:self];
        }
    }

    [self dismiss:animated];
}
```